# Access Opera mini and Firefox browsing history

Tags: android, firefox, opera, browser-history

Is there anyway to access opera mini and firefox's browsing histroy?  They do not save it in the same place that the default browser does.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firefox history is saved in the SQLite database `places.sqlite` in the [Firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Install-and-Update/Profiles-Where-Firefox-stores-your-bookmarks-passwords-and-other/ta-p/4608#w_how-do-i-find-my-profile). Accessing it is tricky in case of Firefox Mobile, I guess that you would need a rooted phone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am going to go ahead and check it as correct since no one else seems willing to respond.  I just plan on contacting firefox and seeing if I can get any information from them

Comment: @michael_andmaf so r u able to get history of others browser in ur mobile except the default browser ?